# Multi-Slider Controller

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to build [this controller in javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZajNh.jpg) but I'm having trouble starting as I'm not getting what I want when I search (I've searched for *sliders* or *volume sliders* or *multi slider* but what I need doesn't show).

To explain;

- There are 25 pressure controllers (the app will start with 2 but then number increases per level/stage)
- All sliders have a common MAX and MIN (lets say 0 and 100 for now)
- Each slider has a bar than has a MIN (green triangle), MAX (red triangle) and an actual (yellow triangle)
- Each of the 3 points can be moved by the user (which sends its value outside of the controller)
- The slider's MIN and MAX cannot go past the actual.
- As silly as this may sound, the MIN and MAX can be the same value as the actual.
- The previous pipeline's MIN cannot be below the next pipeline's MIN
- On as similar note, the next pipeline's MAX cannot be below the previous pipeline's MAX
- These numbers need to be sent out of the controller.

I don't have much javascript experience but so far I have a single horizontal slider with 1 moveable handle (not the triangle I want but it's a start).

I think my first step would be to get it vertical somehow, and put 2 more control points for the MIN and MAX, replicate the code to make more sliders then somehow put validations across slides.

Any help on how to proceed from here would be great. I'd rather not use libraries as we have issues when we use them (not sure if they're being blocked here).

Comment: Are you trying to build this as an HTML element, or on the canvas? If canvas, then I recommend trying to make a second handle on the same slider.

Comment: At the moment I'm building this all as an HTML element. Should I try achieving this via canvas?

Comment: I have never seen this type of slider done in html, but it seems like it would be a much better choice to use canvas. (I'm pretty sure the image you were looking at is also canvas.)